# Flip UitableviewCell one by one when tableview reloadData is called

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uianimation

I want to give flip animation to UITableViewCell when [tableView reloadData] is called so that it will give a cool animation effect in my app. In between flipping of these cells I will update text of labels.

Can UITableViewCell be flipped one by one. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try write the code to animate the `cell.contentView` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"flip Animation" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
  [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                       forView: cell.contentView
                         cache:YES];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Please add this before you return the cell.

Try this way. Hope this helps you.

Comment: That's so incorrect 1) not every displayed cell will be null if the cells are dequeued 2) the cell is obviously not displayed until returned from cellForRowAtIndexPath